# Convert lists in a dataframe column into a single list in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named `df`  with only a column named `Reviews`:

```
Reviews
"Good, Excellent, I love this!"
"This is great, quality is good"
"Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing"
```

How could I convert the column into a single list as follows?:

```
Reviews 
"Good, Excellent, I love this!", "This is great, quality is good", "Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing"
```

I tried `unnest` but it is not suitable in this case as it returns `Error in UseMethod("unnest"): no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: You'll maybe want `nest`, not `unnest`: `tibble(Reviews = c("Good, Excellent, I love this!",
"This is great, quality is good",
"Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing")) |> nest(Reviews = Reviews)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** OP Request:
We can do it this way:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Reviews = paste0('"',Reviews,'"')) %>% 
  summarise(Reviews = toString(Reviews))

 Reviews
1 "Good, Excellent, I love this!", "This is great, quality is good", "Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing"
>
```

**First answer:**
We could use `toString` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(Reviews = toString(Reviews))
```

```
1 Good, Excellent, I love this!, This is great, quality is good, Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing
>
```

Comment: btw, is there a way to ensure that "Good, Excellent, I love this!", "This is great, quality is good", "Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing" are separate strings?

Comment: Please see my update!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
paste0(df$Reviews , collapse = ", ")
```

- output

```
[1] "Good, Excellent, I love this!, This is great, quality is good, Excellent service and quality, Good, amazing"
```